# i want to save data in firebase by date means all the data saved by users is saved on that date

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save data in firebase but i want save by date so that i can fetch it by date.

```
func saveData(){
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    self.date = timestamp

    let fuelDetails:[String:Any] = ["tank_for_refueling" : self.tankForRefuelingTextField.text ?? "",
                                    "fuel_quantity_refueled" : self.fuelQuantityRefueledTextField.text ?? "",
                                    "tank_after_refueling" : self.tankAfterRefuelingTextField.text ?? "",
                                    "date": self.date ?? 0]
    ref.child(Constants.NODE_MAINTENANCE).child("date").child(userid!).child(Constants.NODE_FUEL).childByAutoId().setValue(fuelDetails){(error,databaseRef) in
        if let error = error{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
    func saveData(){
        // ... other code
        let getDate = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        self.date = formatter.string(from: getDate)

        let fuelDetails:[String:Any] = ["tank_for_refueling" : self.tankForRefuelingTextField.text ?? "",
                                        "fuel_quantity_refueled" : self.fuelQuantityRefueledTextField.text ?? "",
                                        "tank_after_refueling" : self.tankAfterRefuelingTextField.text ?? "",
                                        "date": self.date ?? 0]
        ref.child(Constants.NODE_MAINTENANCE).child("\(self.date)").child(userid!).child(Constants.NODE_FUEL).childByAutoId().setValue(fuelDetails){(error,databaseRef) in
            if let error = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
Updated syntax from dots to dashes in case Firestore is trying to parse a child

Comment: self.date = formatter.string(from: getDate) This line appears an error called (Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Double?)

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

Comment: My bad, that is a Swift 3 syntax. You can get updated information for using Dates in [this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date)

Comment: Thanks it will helps me alot